# Can we use multi threading to convert Microsoft Word document to HTML in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ms-word

I have a Windows Service which polls the database for any uploaded documents of type doc, docx, pdf and rtf and convert them to HTML and save them into the local file system. The documents are fetched from database and queued in the memory and then picked up by multiple threads for processing from the shared queue.

The problem I am facing is, the processing become slower over a period of time. The conversion is happening faster in the initial few days say 2 seconds for a document of size 50 KB and slower after few days of time say 20 seconds for the same document. All I can see is a declining trend in the processing time as the days are progressing. I couldn't nail down to what is causing this declining trend. Even restarting of the Windows Service is not helping.

Microsoft Office is installed on the Windows Server for the document conversion. And per day nearly 2000 documents are being converted to HTML.

So my question is can we use multi threading to process Microsoft Word document to HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are already using as much multithreading as is possible - you can't make Word more efficient, just run several Word instances in parallel (which you are doing). I'd suggest spending more time in investigation.

Do some logging/tracing and profiling. Find out which lines of code/methods are the ones that are really slow.

If it turns out to be Word that is slow, try watching it and the system. Where does the slowness come from? Is it using up all the CPU? Perhaps the disk is being accessed too much? Maybe there are too many temporary files gathered somewhere? Or perhaps you run out of RAM and Windows is swapping like mad? In the last case what is using it all? Maybe you're not closing something properly (like Word itself or the files that you make it open)?