# Convert Word automation application to have multiple threads using some sort of task scheduling or multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, ms-word

I have a Word automation project that works well enough in a linear sense, it opens one copy of Word and then processes a lot of documents in order one at a time, I would like to speed this up by creating 4 Word processes/objects and be able to dispatch files to these processes in a distributed manner as and when one of the Word objects becomes available, I don't want to create a new Word instance inside the task as this won't help improve the speed having to create and close Word down repeatedly. Also I would like to be able to set a timeout on the task so that if a document causes an issue then I can abort it flag it as errored and then continue with the rest of the files.

Please also note that by tasks I'm not specifically referring to C# Tasks but just a repeatable piece of work, I'm happy to use Tasks in C# but I'm also happy to use any other pattern or Class that works.

So can anyone recommend a design pattern or some reading material on how I can do this, or even a very simple example either in pseudo code or C#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it would help us answer if you provided some code examples of what is already implemented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use multi threading to convert Microsoft Word document to HTML in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004974/can-we-use-multi-threading-to-convert-microsoft-word-document-to-html-in-c). Also [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a4775ced-fa6d-44bf-b039-5bc72188e823/is-applicationclass-thread-safe?forum=vsto) & [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office): literal [first 3 results from Google: C# multithreading Microsoft Word](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+multithreading+Microsoft+Word)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use multi threading to convert Microsoft Word document to HTML in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004974/can-we-use-multi-threading-to-convert-microsoft-word-document-to-html-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Object Pool pattern? You can keep certain number of Word processes, and can safely share among Tasks. There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501285/correct-way-to-implement-a-resource-pool) that provide an example of this implementation.

It doesn't cover your requirement about timeout, but if you handle errors in each Task and release the resource, which is Word process, then you might not need to consider timeout logic.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @Sphinx. I will pick up questions like that. In terms of this question, he wanted "design pattern" so that I recommended one that can help in such situation described in the question. Sorry, I wrote "Resource Pool", but it should be "Object Pool". I corrected it. now, does this answer makes sense?